# Why is my basic React app heavy after webpack build?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a basic React app (2 small pages and a redux store), which is supposed to be very light. But when building the final bundle, webpack tells me that the bundle is 1.12 MiB, while the recommended limit is 244 KiB. Yet, I have made optimisations, with Terser plugin & code splitting.

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```js
const path = require("path"); 
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin"); 
const Dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack"); 
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin"); 

module.exports = () => {
  const env = require("dotenv").config({ path: __dirname + "/.env" }); 
  return {
    mode: "development",
    entry: "./src/Index.js",
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, "./dist"),
      filename: "[name].[hash].bundle.js", 
      publicPath: "/",
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".js", "jsx", ".json"], 
      alias: {
        components: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components/"), 
        pages: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/pages/"),
        store: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/store/"),
        src: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/"),
      },
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: { loader: "babel-loader" },
        },
        { test: /\.css$/, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"] },
        { test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/, use: ["file-loader"] },
        { test: /\.html$/, use: [{ loader: "html-loader" }] },
      ],
    },
    devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true, 
      port: 3000, 
      hot: true, 
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "./src/index.html",
      }),
      new Dotenv(),
    ],
    optimization: {
      minimize: true, 
      minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()], 
      splitChunks: { chunks: "all" },
    },
  };
};
```

And here is my package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "html-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.6",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: First step would be to use [webpack-bundle-analyser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) to check whats getting bundled and taking up how much size.

Comment: I can't launch webpack-bundle-analyzer. I typed yarn webpack-bundle-analyzer bundle/output/stats.json but I have an error.